# Detect nearby mobile devices from an iOS app

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Is it possible to create an iOS app which will scan for nearby mobile devices (eg. iPhone, Android, iPad etc), without needing to run any custom app on those nearby mobile devices?

I have tried using CoreBluetooth like so, running on my iPhone 6+:

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

But the only nearby device it detects is my iMac, it will not detect my iPad Air 2, or my bluetooth earpiece.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Core Bluetooth works only with Bluetooth Low Energy devices, not the classic Bluetooth. I suppose your earpiece is the Bluetooth classic device.

Comment: I'm more interested in detecting mobile devices, eg. An iPad Air 2. These should be BLE?

Comment: Yes, they are. But in order to be discoverable, a device has to advertise one or more BLE services. You can implement `CBPeripheralManager` to do that and there's even sample code from Apple for the "scanner" and "peripheral" side.

Comment: It sounds like what I want to do is not possible without having a custom app on both sides? In other words, what I would like to do is detect nearby iOS devices that are not running an app that I wrote. I don't actually want to pair - just detect the name/identifier.

Comment: Would an iOS device not already be advertising BLE services, such as hotspot or handoff?

Comment: Detecting Hotspot or Handoff BLE services? That would be interesting, but unfortunately I don't know if it's possible. Core Bluetooth does not allow you to access the "raw" Bluetooth Low Energy advertisement packets, so Apple probably does filter out some stuff. Go on and ask about it in a new question :). If you want to detect only iOS devices (and no other BLE devices / accessories), you can also use Multipeer Connectivity framework (which is a bit easier to use), but you will still have to run a custom app on both sides.

Comment: I think simply detecting nearby iOS devices would be sufficient, though it would be nice to detect nearby Android devices as well. It sounds like this is probably not possible. If you want to put this as an answer, I'll leave the question open for a bit longer, but if nothing else comes along I'll accept your answer.

Comment: only bluetooth? could be anything else?

Comment: It does not have to be Bluetooth. The aim is to be able to detect a nearby mobile phone, and recognise in the future when nearby that same mobile phone again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Bluetooth works only with Bluetooth Low Energy (a.k.a. Bluetooth 4.0) devices, not the classic Bluetooth ones. In order to be discoverable, a device has to advertise one or more BLE services. You can implement `CBPeripheralManager` to do that and there's even [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927) from Apple for the "scanner" and "peripheral" side. Note that this way you can also discover or be discovered by other mobile devices, like Android smartphones.

I don't know if it's possible to detect Hotspot or Handoff BLE services. Core Bluetooth does not allow you to access the "raw" Bluetooth Low Energy advertisement packets, so Apple probably does filter out some stuff.

If you want to detect only iOS devices (and no other BLE devices / accessories), you can also use Multipeer Connectivity framework. I personally find it a bit easier to use and it even  provides a built-in ["discovered devices" view](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/index.html). But you still have to run a custom app on both sides.

Comment: Multipeer is complete garbage, by the way.  It fails in mysterious ways over time and also fails trying to connect when there are more than 8 devices connected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bluetooth low Energy, it will only detect the peripheral of BLE devices .
However there is limitation of the range . By the documentation the BLE devices range is around 300 meter .You can get signal strength in CBCentralManager peripheral method :

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

Here RSSI is your signal strength .But the peripheral device has to be BLE enable i.e. bluetooth version 4.0 or above

Comment: Everything I am testing is together on my desk

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to put whatever you're building on the App Store, you can jailbreak your iPhone and get direct access to the packets.

[Bluetooth Companion](http://www.bestcydiatweaks.com/bluetooth-companion.html), available in Cydia, will show you bluetooth packets on your phone. I'm not sure if that project's source is available, but you could look at other project like [BTStack](https://code.google.com/p/btstack/) (there's a good [Getting Started guide here](https://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/GettingStarted)).

Comment: Although the intended target is an Enterprise app rather than App Store, jailbreaking is not an option. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the perspective of someone involved in embedded systems development. As was previously stated BLE only detects peripherals of other BLE devices, therefore I do not think Bluetooth technology is the best option for an app that detects nearby mobile devices.

Your app should consist of two detection features. One should have used Bluetooth to detect regular PC's and use GPS to detect other mobile devices, as it is the only other peripheral I believe is present in android and 4G ipad mini etc.

For your earpiece, if it is not detected then I do not know of any software solution that would modify hardware incompatibilities, so i would recommend you get an earpiece that is compatible with the bluetooth device.

Your problem is not a software one, it lies in the hardware limitations of the devices.