# Bluetooth sensor iOS app

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there any way to list all the Bluetooth enabled iDevices in my application.

I tried out with coreBluetooth framework but it needs atleast two devices (central and peripheral) and communication happens only between these two devices.
But my requirement is: The application installed on my device should list all the iOS devices with Bluetooth enabled(these devices will not have any app installed on them).
Please post your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178293/how-to-get-list-of-available-bluetooth-devices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect nearby mobile devices from an iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242392/detect-nearby-mobile-devices-from-an-ios-app)